# Race-free way to asynchronously start AND cancel I/O on another thread in Windows

Tags: c, asynchronous, winapi, overlapped-io

Background: generally, if we want to **force** an operation to happen asynchronously (to avoid blocking the main thread), using `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` is insufficient, because the operation can still complete synchronously.

So let's say that, to avoid this, we defer the operation to a worker thread dedicated to I/O. This avoids blocking the main thread.

Now the main thread can use [`CancelIoEx(HANDLE, LPOVERLAPPED)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/cancelioex-func) to cancel the I/O operation initiated (say, via `ReadFile`) by the worker.

However, for `CancelIoEx` to succeed,  the main thread needs a way to guarantee that the operation has in fact *started*, otherwise there is nothing to cancel.

The obvious solution here is to make the worker thread set an event **after** its call to e.g. `ReadFile` returns, but that now brings us back to the original problem: since `ReadFile` can block, we'll have defeated the entire purpose of having a worker thread in the first place, which was to ensure that the main thread isn't blocked on the I/O.

**What's the "right" way to solve this?** Is there a good way to actually force an I/O operation to happen asynchronously while still being able to request its cancellation later in a race-free manner when the I/O hasn't yet finished?

The only thing I can think of is to set a timer to periodically call `CancelIoEx` while the I/O hasn't completed, but that seems incredibly ugly. Is there a better/more robust solution?

Comment: `needs a way to guarantee that the operation has in fact started, otherwise there is nothing to cancel.` So where is the problem? The effect for the main thread will be exactly the same, worker thread can ignore cancel if the operation did not start yet.

Comment: This really seems like an XY problem.  What **problem** does cancelling an already-scheduled IO purport to solve? And I'd seriously question this design in the first place.  "OK, I gotta do X.  Oh, wait, I changed my mind! **CANCEL X!!!**"  And if your reply is. "Well, it's critical to be able to cancel X", how do you plan on undoing X if it's already been completed?  If it's "critical"  to be able to cancel the operation, then it's also "critical" to figure out how to undo the IO operation. And if it's not important to be able to undo it, it's not really important to be able to cancel it.

Comment: It shouldn't be the main thread that calls CancelIo(), it should be done by the worker thread.  Define an event that you signal in the main thread to tell the worker thread to stop doing whatever it is doing.  WaitForMultipleObjects in the worker to check for that event, as well as the completion of an overlapped I/O.

Comment: *"we want to **force** an operation to happen asynchronously"* - That sounds odd. What specific problem are you trying to solve by disallowing an operation to retire immediately?

Comment: @0___________: The problem is that a moment later there **will** be something to cancel, i.e. you would've just called `CancelIoEx` too early. The question is how to avoid this race condition.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: *"How do you plan on undoing X if it's already been completed?"* I don't, I just discard the result of the read if it's already completed. Doesn't mean I shouldn't try to cancel it if I can... that's kinda the entire point of `CancelIoEx`: to try to cancel I/O on a best-effort basis. It's not rocket science right?

Comment: @HansPassant: But this is about `CancelIoEx`, not `CancelIo`. The documentation [explicitly says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/cancelioex-func) *"The `CancelIoEx` function allows you to cancel requests in threads other than the calling thread"*, so surely the answer can't be "you're not supposed to use `CancelIoEx` to cancel requests in other threads", can it? And wouldn't that make it impossible to request cancellation of I/O operations that complete synchronously...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need in general do next:

- every file handle which you use to asynchronous I/O incapsulate to
  some c/c++ object (let name it `IO_OBJECT`)
- this object need have reference count
- before start asynchronous I/O operation - you need allocate another
  object, which incapsulate `OVERLAPPED` or `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` (let name
  it `IO_IRP`) inside `IO_IRP` store referenced pointer to `IO_OBJECT`
  and specific io information - I/O code (read, write, etc) buffers
  pointers,..
- check return code of I/O operation for determinate, are will be I/O
  callback (packet queued to iocp or apc) or if operation fail (will be
  no callback) - call callback by self just with error code
- I/O manager save pointer which you pass to I/O in  [`IRP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_irp) structure (*UserApcContext*) and
  pass it back to you when I/O finished (if use win32 api this pointer
  equal pointer to OVERLAPPED in case native api - you can direct by
  self control this pointer)
- when I/O finishid (if not synchronous fail at begin) - callback with
  final I/O status will be called
- here you got back pointer to `IO_IRP` (`OVERLAPPED`) - call method of
  `IO_OBJECT` and release it reference, delete `IO_IRP`
- if you at some point can close object handle early (not in
  destructor) - implement some run-down protection, for not access
  handle after close
- [run-down protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/run-down-protection) very similar to weak-refefence, unfortunatelly no
  user mode api for this, but not hard implement this byself

from any thread, where you have pointer (referenced of course) to your object, you can call `CancelIoEx` or close object handle - if file have IOCP, when last handle  to file is closed - all I/O operations will be canceled. however for close - you need not call `CloseHandle` direct but begin run-down and call `CloseHandle` when run-down completed (inside some *ReleaseRundownProtection* call (this is demo name, no such api)

some minimal tipical implementation:

```
class __declspec(novtable) IO_OBJECT 
{
    friend class IO_IRP;

    virtual void IOCompletionRoutine(
        ULONG IoCode, 
        ULONG dwErrorCode, 
        ULONG dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, 
        PVOID Pointer) = 0;
    
    void AddRef();
    void Release();

    HANDLE _hFile = 0;
    LONG _nRef = 1;
    //...
};


class IO_IRP : public OVERLAPPED 
{
    IO_OBJECT* _pObj;
    PVOID Pointer;
    ULONG _IoCode;
    
    IO_IRP(IO_OBJECT* pObj, ULONG IoCode, PVOID Pointer) : 
        _pObj(pObj), _IoCode(IoCode), Pointer(Pointer)
    {
        pObj->AddRef();
    }
    
    ~IO_IRP()
    {
        _pObj->Release();
    }
    
    VOID CALLBACK IOCompletionRoutine(
        ULONG dwErrorCode,
        ULONG dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
        )
    {
        _pObj->IOCompletionRoutine(_IoCode, 
            dwErrorCode, dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, Pointer);

        delete this;
    }

    static VOID CALLBACK FileIOCompletionRoutine(
        ULONG status,
        ULONG dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
        LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
        )
    {
        static_cast<IO_IRP*>(lpOverlapped)->IOCompletionRoutine(
            RtlNtStatusToDosError(status), dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
    }

    static BOOL BindIoCompletion(HANDLE hObject)
    {
        return BindIoCompletionCallback(hObject, FileIOCompletionRoutine, 0));
    }
    
    void CheckErrorCode(ULONG dwErrorCode)
    {
        switch (dwErrorCode)
        {
        case NOERROR:
        case ERROR_IO_PENDING:
            return ;
        }
        IOCompletionRoutine(dwErrorCode, 0);
    }
    
    void CheckError(BOOL fOk)
    {
        return CheckErrorCode(fOk ? NOERROR : GetLastError());
    }
};


///// start some I/O // no run-downprotection on file

if (IO_IRP* irp = new IO_IRP(this, 'some', 0))
{
    irp->CheckErrorCode(ReadFile(_hFile, buf, cb, 0, irp));
}

///// start some I/O // with run-downprotection on file

if (IO_IRP* irp = new IO_IRP(this, 'some', 0))
{
    ULONG dwError = ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE;
    
    if (AcquireRundownProtection())
    {
        dwError = ReadFile(_hFile, buf, cb, 0, irp) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
        ReleaseRundownProtection();
    }
    
    irp->CheckErrorCode(dwError);
}
```

[some](https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/tree/master/ASIO) more full implementation

---

> However, for `CancelIoEx` to succeed, the main thread needs a way to
> guarantee that the operation has in fact started, otherwise there is
> nothing to cancel.

yes, despite you can safe call `CancelIoEx` at any time, even if no active I/O on file, by fact another thread can start new I/O operation already after you call `CancelIoEx`. with this call you can cancel current known single started operations. for instance - you begin conect `ConnectEx` and update UI (enable *Cancel* button). when `ConnectEx` finished - you post message to UI (disable *Cancel* button). if user press *Cancel* until I/O (`ConnectEx`) ative - you call `CancelIoEx` - as result connect will be canceled or finished normally bit early. in case periodic operations (for instance `ReadFile` in loop) - usually `CancelIoEx` not correct way for stop such loop. instead you need call `CloseHandle` from control thread - -which effective cancell all current I/O on file.

---

about how `ReadFile` and any asynchronous I/O api work and are we can force faster return from api call.

1. I/O manager check input parameter, convert handles (file handle to
   `FILE_OBJECT`) to pointers, check permissions, etc. if some error on
   this stage - error returned for caller and I/O finished
2. I/O manager call driver. driver (or several drivers - top driver can
   pass request to another) handle I/O request (`IRP`) and finally
   return to I/O manager. it can return or `STATUS_PENDING`, which mean
   that I/O still not completed or complete I/O (call
   `IofCompleteRequest`) and return another status. any status other
   than `STATUS_PENDING` mean that I/O completed (with success, error
   or canceled, but completed)
3. I/O mahager check for `STATUS_PENDING` and if file opened for
   synchronous I/O (flag `FO_SYNCHRONOUS_IO` ) begin wait in place,
   until I/O completed. in case file opened for asynchronous I/O - I/O
   manager by self never wait and return status for caller, including
   `STATUS_PENDING`

we can break wait in stage **3** by call `CancelSynchronousIo`. but if wait was inside driver at stage **2** - impossible break this wait in any way. any `Cancel*Io*` or `CloseHandle` not help here. in case we use asynchronous file handle - I/O manager never wait in **3** and if api call wait - it wait in **2** (driver handler) where we can not break wait.

as resutl - we **can not force** I/O call on **asynchronous** file return faster. if driver under some condition will be wait.

and more - why we can not break driver wait, but can stop I/O manager wait. because unknown - how, on which object (or just Sleep), for which condition driver wait. what will be if we break thread wait before contidions meet.. so if driver wait - it will be wait. in case I/O manager - he wait for IRP complete. and for break this wait - need complete IRP. for this exist api, which mark IRP as canceled and call driver callback (driver must set this callback in case it return before complete request). driver in this callback complete IRP, this is awaken I/O manager from wait (again it wait only on synchrnous files) and return to caller

also very important not confuse - end of I/O and end of api call. in case synchronous file - this is the same. api returned only after I/O completed. but for asynchronous I/O this is different things - I/O can still be active, after api call is return (if it return `STATUS_PENDING` or `ERROR_IO_PENDING` for win32 layer).

we can ask for I/O complete early by cancel it. and usually (if driver well designed) this work. but we can not ask api call return early in case asynchronous I/O file. we can not control when, how fast, I/O call (`ReadFile` in concrete case) return. but can early cancel I/O request **after** I/O call (`ReadFile`) return . more exactly after driver return from **2** and because I/O manager never wait in **3** - can say that I/O call return after driver return control.

---

if one thread use file handle, while another can close it, without any synchronization - this of course lead to raice and errors. in best case `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` can returned from api call, after another thread close handle. in worst case - handle can be reused after close and we begin use wrong handle with undefined results. for protect from this case need use handle only inside run-down protection (similar to [convert](https://gist.github.com/kchugalinskiy/e0f6373e1ef011dd138b9aeecf2cf247#file-memory-h-L7) weak reference to strong ).
demo implementation:

```
class IoObject
{
    HANDLE _hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    LONG _lock = 0x80000000;

public:
    HANDLE LockHandle() 
    {
        LONG Value, PreviousValue;

        if (0 > (Value = _lock))
        {
            do 
            {
                PreviousValue = InterlockedCompareExchangeNoFence(&_lock, Value + 1, Value);

                if (PreviousValue == Value) return _hFile;

            } while (0 > (Value = PreviousValue));
        }
    
        return 0;
    }

    void UnlockHandle()
    {
        if (InterlockedDecrement(&_lock) == 0)
        {
            _hFile = 0; // CloseHandle(_hFile)
        }
    }

    void Close()
    {
        if (LockHandle())
        {
            _interlockedbittestandreset(&_lock, 31);
            UnlockHandle();
        }
    }

    void WrongClose()
    {
        _hFile = 0; // CloseHandle(_hFile)
    }

    BOOL IsHandleClosed()
    {
        return _hFile == 0;
    }
};

ULONG WINAPI WorkThread(IoObject* pObj)
{
    ULONG t = GetTickCount();
    int i = 0x1000000;
    do 
    {
        if (HANDLE hFile = pObj->LockHandle())
        {
            SwitchToThread(); // simulate delay

            if (pObj->IsHandleClosed())
            {
                __debugbreak();
            }

            pObj->UnlockHandle();
        }
        else
        {
            DbgPrint("[%x]: handle closed ! (%u ms)\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), GetTickCount() - t);
            break;
        }
    } while (--i);

    return 0;
}

ULONG WINAPI WorkThreadWrong(IoObject* pObj)
{
    ULONG t = GetTickCount();
    int i = 0x10000000;
    do 
    {
        if (pObj->IsHandleClosed())
        {
            DbgPrint("[%x]: handle closed ! (%u ms)\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), GetTickCount() - t);
            break;
        }
        
        SwitchToThread(); // simulate delay

        if (pObj->IsHandleClosed())
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }

    } while (--i);

    return 0;
}

void CloseTest()
{
    IoObject obj;

    ULONG n = 8;
    do 
    {
        if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0x1000, (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)WorkThread, &obj, 0, 0))
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
    } while (--n);

    Sleep(50);
//#define _WRONG_
#ifdef _WRONG_
    obj.WrongClose();
#else
    obj.Close();
#endif
    MessageBoxW(0,0,0,0);
}
```

with `WrongClose();` call we permanent will be catch `__debugbreak()` (use after close) in `WorkThread[Wrong]`. but with `obj.Close();` and `WorkThread` we must never catch exception. also note that `Close()` is `lock-free` and caller of it never wait/hang even if api call inside rundown-protection will wait.

Comment: *"Instead you need call `CloseHandle` from control thread -- which effective cancels all current I/O on file."* I did think about this, but this introduces another race condition: handle recycling. The thread will now call `ReadFile` on a handle that might end up pointing to something else entirely, resulting in corruption. That's much worse than the original problem we're trying to prevent.

Comment: @user541686 - but i write exactly about this in answer - you must access handle only inside run-down protection. look at the end of my code - here how it used. possible user mode [implementation](https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/blob/master/INC/rundown.h)

Comment: @user541686 if we use rundown-protection for some resourse (handle in concrete case), after we acquire it - `AcquireRundownProtection()` return true, we have garante that handle will be not closed, until call to `ReleaseRundownProtection()`. from control thread we can at any time begin rundown. after this - any call to `AcquireRundownProtection()` return false, but handle will be closed only after last call to `ReleaseRundownProtection()`. very near to weak-reference in c++ (if it's closer to you) except you still convert weak to strong until exist strong reference.

Comment: @user541686 so possible and say - that we have logical weak-reference in object (`IO_OBJECT`) to handle and before use handle in I/O call - convert weak to strong reference and than release strong. control thread have strong reference and when want stop - release strong reference. run-down only add flag to this - that prevent convert weak to strong after begin rundown, even still exist some strong

Comment: internal weak_ptr based on [`_Incref_nz()`](https://gist.github.com/kchugalinskiy/e0f6373e1ef011dd138b9aeecf2cf247#file-memory-h-L7) run-down use almost this (1 bit used as flag)

Comment: I don't think that approach solves the issue? Let's say your worker thread performs `if (AcquireRundownProtection())`, then pauses just before `ReadFile` is called. Now it's your main thread's turn to run. If the main thread calls `CancelIoEx`, it will fail, because there is no I/O in progress. If the main thread calls `CloseHandle`, then `ReadFile` will attempt to run on a recycled handle. If the main thread merely decreases the refcount on the handle (with your "rundown protection" mechanism), then `ReadFile` will run, but the operation won't be canceled at all. Right?

Comment: @user541686 - but i say about `CloseHandle` ! not `CancelIoEx` (for it not need rundown protection). and afraid you not undertand me.. *If the main thread calls CloseHandle* - it must not direct call `CloseHandle` ! in this case any run-down protection senseless. it must begin run-down instead (or release strong reference if want). and actually `CloseHandle` will be called after rundown released.

Comment: @user541686 - i already many years work on asynchronous I/O in windows and have knowledge in topic. solution 100% correct and have no raice. if we call `ReadFile` inside acquire/release rundown protection - it will be not run on closed handle. and after `CloseHandle` will be called (this must be last handle to object) all I/O which already strarted will be canceled and we not start new I/O after this too

Comment: @user541686 for instance, when i call [`Close`](https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/blob/master/ASIO/io.cpp#L81) in self lib code - it not direct call `CloseHandle` but start [run-down](https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/blob/master/ASIO/io.h#L111). really `CloseHandle` (or may be `closesocket` ) will be called from ["release run-down protection"](https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/blob/master/ASIO/io.cpp#L71) on arbitrary thread (may be from main, may be from worked)
possible i focus on general work with I/O and not on path for run-down protection and handle close

Comment: Yes I understand *you* don't call `CloseHandle` directly. I was trying to explain to you what all the 3 possibilities are, whether or not they're consistent with your approach. Your approach relies on deferring the cancellation and/or closure until **after** `ReadFile` is called, right? Which means you *cannot cancel the I/O in the middle of `ReadFile`*. Right? You wait until `ReadFile` has **already finished** before you close the handle and/or cancel the I/O, which is **too late** to be useful: the I/O may have completed synchronously at that point because `ReadFile` can *block*. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239645/discussion-between-rbmm-and-user541686).